# Connecting to a Windows Azure storage in php

Tags: php, azure, storage

I have written such a php code statement to connect a Windows Azure storage account. But when I run it, it causes the page redirection.

```
$blob = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob(
'blob.core.windows.net',
'http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/',
'myaccountkey'
);
```

I couldn't solve the problem.

How can I fix this?

Thank you...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry for latency Gaurav. I have created a few containers in azure. Now I want to connect my storage account from php. And later I will fetch the files I put in azure.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/?

Comment: No Gaurav, actually I looked at here: http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/tutorial-using-blob-storage

Comment: Oh. That's really old one :). At that time, there was no official Azure PHP SDK from Microsoft. Now there's one which you can download from here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/. The source code for this SDK is also available on Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php. Please use that. Let me know if you need an example (though I don't work in PHP so your code will be better than mine :)).

Comment: I've already downloaded PHP SDK from Microsoft. :)

Comment: OK. But are you using that in your code? What's the problem you're encountering now?

Comment: Actually I need an example, Gaurav. :) If you would like to give an example, I wouldn't say no. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the example below. It connects to a storage account and creates a blob container by the name `hasan`. Just use your account name and key to try it out.

```
<?php
require_once 'WindowsAzure.php';
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
use WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\SetBlobPropertiesOptions;
try {
  $containerName = "hasan";
  $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=<youraccountname>;AccountKey=<youraccountkey>';
  $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString); 
 $ok = $blobRestProxy->createContainer($containerName);
  echo "Error : " . $ok;
  }
catch(ServiceException $e){
$code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Gaurav. :) You are very helpful.. I'm trying now.

Comment: Why it gives the error of redirection page loop again?

Comment: Can you share your code please? Please update your original question by adding your new code below your original code. Also what do you mean by `error of redirection page loop`? Can you please explain?

Comment: I'm sorry, course.php opens, but I cannot do anything on course.php page, because a loop occures which results the page refresh ever.

Comment: You got me here :) ... Unfortunately I don't know much about this one to help you out. Sorry!!! But one thing I would suggest you do **immediately is change your database password and storage account key** as they are available in plain text on the link you shared and anybody can misuse it.